# Mocking queryForObject using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock queryForObject but I get NPE. Looks like I am setting everything needed.

`long identity = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject( getStatementConfiguration().getStatement( KeyConstants.CLIENT_USER_VENDOR_IDENTITY), Long.class);` is where I get NPE.

MUT

```
 public IClientUserVendorDto insert(final IClientUserVendorDto dto) throws DaoException {
try {
    String sql1 = getStatementConfiguration().getStatement(KeyConstants.CLIENT_USER_VENDOR_RETRIEVE);

    Object args[] = new Object[] { 
            dto.getClientUserId(),
            dto.getVendor().getId(),
            dto.getIdentifier(),
            Boolean.TRUE,
        dto.getCreatedBy(),
        dto.getLastModifiedBy()};

    //insert
    String sql = getStatementConfiguration().getStatement(KeyConstants.CLIENT_USER_VENDOR_INSERT);
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, args);

    //Retrieve
    long identity = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject( getStatementConfiguration().getStatement( KeyConstants.CLIENT_USER_VENDOR_IDENTITY), Long.class);
    return (ClientUserVendorDto) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql1, new Object[] {identity}, new ClientUserVendorRowMapper());
} catch (Exception e) {
    String message = "An exception occurred inserting a Client User Vendor.";
    IExceptionHandlerResponse r = getExceptionHandler().handleData(e, DaoException.class, message);
    if (r.isRethrow()) {
        DaoException daoe = (DaoException) r.getThrowable();
        throw daoe;
    }
    throw (DaoException)r.getThrowable();
} finally {
}
}
```

Junit

```
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    AppContext.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    IVendorDto v = new VendorDto();

    IClientUserVendorDto userDto = new ClientUserVendorDto();
    userDto.setActive(true);
    userDto.setClientUserId(new Long(1220));
    userDto.setIdentifier("JUnit-ID");
    userDto.setVendor(v);
    v.setId(new Long(123));
    userDto.setCreatedBy("SYSTEM");
    userDto.setLastModifiedBy("Junit");

    ClientUserVendorDao dao = new ClientUserVendorDao();
    dao.setConfiguration(daoConfiguration);
    dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

    BaseJdbcDao baseDao = Mockito.mock(BaseJdbcDao.class);
    BaseDao baseDao2 = Mockito.mock(BaseDao.class);
    IStatementConfiguration stmtConfiguration = Mockito.mock(IStatementConfiguration.class);

    Mockito.when(baseDao.getJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);

    IDaoConfiguration configuration = new DaoConfiguration();
    configuration.setStatement(stmtConfiguration);
    dao.setConfiguration(configuration);

    Mockito.when(baseDao.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject( Mockito.any(String.class), (RowMapper<Long>) Mockito.any(Object.class))).thenReturn(123L);

    userDto = dao.insert(userDto);

}
```

Comment: Debug up to that line then check the variables.  Find the one that is null, it's either getJdbcTemplate() or getStatementConfiguration()

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue. queryForObject was not returning a long value. So, here is the fix for it.

```
@Test
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    IClientUserVendorDto iClientUserVendorDto = new ClientUserVendorDto();
    iClientUserVendorDto.setClientUserId(new Long(1007));

    IVendorDto iVendorDto = new VendorDto();
    iVendorDto.setId(new Long(1008));

    iClientUserVendorDto.setVendor(iVendorDto);
    iClientUserVendorDto.setIdentifier("GW_SYS_USER");
    iClientUserVendorDto.setActive(true);
    iClientUserVendorDto.setCreatedBy("SYSTEM");
    iClientUserVendorDto.setLastModifiedBy("SYSTEM");

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    ClientUserVendorDao clientUserVendroDao2 = Mockito.mock(ClientUserVendorDao.class);
    IDaoConfiguration iDaoConfiguration = Mockito.mock(IDaoConfiguration.class);
    IStatementConfiguration iStatementConfiguration = Mockito.mock(IStatementConfiguration.class);

    Mockito.when(iDaoConfiguration.getStatement()).thenReturn(iStatementConfiguration);
    Mockito.when(iStatementConfiguration.getStatement(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn("JUnit");
    Mockito.when(clientUserVendroDao2.getJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Matchers.eq(Long.class))).thenReturn(1007L);

    ClientUserVendorDao clientUserVendorDao = new ClientUserVendorDao();
    clientUserVendorDao.setConfiguration(iDaoConfiguration);
    clientUserVendorDao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

    iClientUserVendorDto =  clientUserVendorDao.insert(iClientUserVendorDto);
```